# what is the first parameter('.') of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)

set @cols = (select distinct quotename(name) 
             from students 
             for xml path(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
exec @cols
```

What is the first parameter ('.') of value function, and why am I getting this error?

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   The name '[pavan][pramod][sachin][shital][shubham][sonika]' is not a valid
>   identifier.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question there are two issues:

1) The actual question: What is the dot in the XPath

The dot points to the `current` element. Reading XML with `XPath` / `XQuery` is like navigating through a tree. You can move deeper and you can move back.

Without any action, the current element is the first (in most cases this is the root) element.

But some methods, especially `.query()` and `.nodes()` set the current element to another one.

Check this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
(N'<root>
    <Level1 nodeLevel="level1">
        <Level2 nodeLevel="level2">test</Level2>
    </Level1>
</root>');

SELECT @xml.query('.') AS ThisIsTheCurrentNode

SELECT @xml.query('/root/Level1').query('.') AS NowLevel1IsTheCurrentNode

SELECT @xml.query('/root/Level1').query('.').value('(Level1/@nodeLevel)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS AndThisLevel1Attribute
      ,@xml.query('/root/Level1/Level2').query('.').value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS AndThisLevel2Value
```

2) Why is there this error?

You try

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)
set @cols = (select distinct quotename(name) 
             from students 
             for xml path(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
exec @cols
```

And you get

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 3 The name
>   '[pavan][pramod][sachin][shital][shubham][sonika]' is not a valid
>   identifier.

What do you expect? Your statement will do nothing more than to concatenate the (quoted) values of `students.name`. Hence the content of `@cols` will be nothing more than the string you get as error. There is not even a separator character...

You try to **execute** a list of names... I can only hope, that this is not what you **really** want :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try select instead of exec. Because you are setting `@cols` value as name not some query.

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)
set @cols=(select distinct quotename(name) from students for xml path(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
SELECT @cols
```

When you are using `FOR XML PATH('')` you are making a XML value contain all name from students table like below variable `@myDoc`

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml  

SET @myDoc = '
<Name> Mr. X 
</Name>  
<Name> Mr. Y
</Name>
<Name> Mr. Z
</Name> '
```

With `value('.', 'varchar(max)')` you are just selecting all values excluding xml tags and convert it to varchar(max).

```
SELECT  @myDoc.value('.', 'varchar(max)' )  -- will return 'Mr. X  Mr. Y Mr. Z'
```

You can also select a specific name with order like below

```
SELECT  @myDoc.value('(/Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)' )  -- will return Mr. X
SELECT  @myDoc.value('(/Name)[2]', 'varchar(max)' )  -- will return Mr. Y
SELECT  @myDoc.value('(/Name)[3]', 'varchar(max)' )  -- will return Mr. Z
```

Comment: what is ' .  ' in value parameter

Comment: That means it will return the values only excluding xml tags. Wait for my updated answer.

Comment: @TanjimRahman *That means it will return the values only excluding xml tags* is not correct. The `.` is a pointer to the current location of your navigation via `XPath`. The reason for a result without dedicated elements is the combination of a computation (usage of `QUOTENAME`), which leads to an unnamed column, together with the empty `PATH('')`, which - again - leads to no element names,

Comment: @Shnugo agreed and thats the correct explanation.I just want to say about the query mentioned in question what output will return by . param in `value`.